# how to read a text file in java and set up some criteria

Tags: java

I have a text file in my computer which i am reading form my java program , now i want to build some criteria

here is my Notepad File :

```
   #Students
   #studentId   studentkey  yearLevel   studentName token   
   358314           432731243   12          Adrian      Afg56       
   358297           432730131   12          Armstrong   YUY89       
   358341           432737489   12          Atkins      JK671   

        #Teachers
        #teacherId  teacherkey    yearLevel teacherName token   
        358314          432731243   12          Adrian      N7ACD       
        358297          432730131   12          Armstrong   EY2C        
        358341          432737489   12          Atkins      F4NGH
```

when I read from this note pad file , i get the exact data as it is in my application , but now i want to check if the token which a user just entered on my main page e,g i have the token "JK671" , if this belongs to the token present in the students or Teachers above ?

```
      output should be like "the token JK671 belongs to Student "..
```

how could i achieve this ?
thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should also include the classes / datastructures you use to represent the data in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll achieve this by iterating on your teachers and students, and comparing their code with the given token.

If the codes are unique identifiers, and your program must search by code, then you should creta e a `Map<String, Teacher>` and an `Map<String, Student>`, where the keys of the maps are the teacher/student codes, and use the map's containsKey method to know if such a teacher or student code exists. This will lean to O(1) searches rather than O(n).

Comment: thanks , that i was looking for , like how can i iterate over student or teacher , if this table was in SQL i can easily iterate , by putting where clause and stuff but how can i iterate it over here if you could plz give me a short code

Comment: @junaidp Use the [tutorials](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/Collection.html), they are filled with sample code

Comment: or my question should be like how can i put a certain data from my notepad into some array ,if i can achieve this then i can easily iterate them

Comment: I thought this part was done already. Read each line, and use `String.split()` to get every part or a teacher/student. Consider using a more well-defined and parsable format like XML or JSON, or using a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can either store everything in a db, or have Teacher and Student class inherit from a common superclass, and have an hashtable where the key is your token, and the value is the Teacher/Student that correspond to the token itself.